# Spring Boot 2.1 with Tomcat 9 Http2 not working with gzip

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, http2, http-compression

My Spring Boot 2.1 Application has Tomcat 9 for the Servlets. I would like to use Http/2 and Gzip compression. In the application.properties file are these flags enabled:

```
server.compression.enabled=true
server.http2.enabled=true
```

The Http/2 protocol is enabled but the gzip compression does not work. Has somebody an idea howto use Http/2 and compression in a Spring Boot 2.1 application together?

Comment: are you using embedded tomcat? and have you specified `server.compression.mime-types`?

Comment: I am using embedded tomcat and I have added the `server.compression.mime-types` wthout getting the compression. The application also uses https.